# Why isn't this Vlookup loop macro working?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

I am trying to write an Excel macro that will perform a VLOOKUP on cells 9:100 of column K on 1155 individual sheets (named Page 1, Page 2, etc) of a workbook.  I want to run the macro in another workbook, though.  So I'm trying to target the cells in one workbook to populate cell values in another.

I have this.  However, when I run it, all it does is replace the contents of the specified cells on the first sheet with "#VALUE!".  It doesn't do anything to the other sheets.

```
Sub SearchPages()
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim value As Variant
Dim result As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("file.xls")

For Each cell In Range("K9:K100")
    value = cell.value
    result = "Not Found"
    
    For i = 1 To 1155
        On Error Resume Next
        result = Application.VLookup(value, "Page " & i & "!K:N", 4, False)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not IsError(result) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    cell.value = result
Next cell

End Sub
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: When using `Application.VLookup()`  (ie. not `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`) then there's no runtime error if no match is made, so you shouldn't need the `On Error Resume Next` provided your lookup table range is valid (see answer from 2MuchC0ff33 for that fix)

Answer (score 0):

The error lies at `"Page " & i & "!K:N"`

When using `Application.VLookup`, you need to use the VBA range referencing `Range("K:N")` so you may have to change that section of the code to `wb.Sheets("Page " & i).Range("K:N")`